# Multiple fields in one sheet mapping to single field in another sheet

Tags: database, ms-access, rdbms

I need help designing the following architecture. Say Table 1 has a list of companies along with their information. Then Table 2 has a list of "primary" companies, followed by multiple fields denoting the companies that they do business with ("secondary" companies). So the first field in Table 2 is the "primary" company, and then there could follow up to 20 columns, each with a single entry of a company that does business with the "primary company". Each of those companies are listed in Table 1. I want to be able to tie the information about those "secondary companies" in with the information about them in Table 1. For example, I want to be able to see how many "secondary" companies in Table 2 are from California. I each company listed once in Table 1 along with headquarters locations; but each company in Table 2 is in a distinct column. I'm just getting confused about how to structure this, because when I try to make a query relationship between Table 1 and Table 2, I end up making a join between "Company" in Table 1 and every column in Table 2. Not good, right?

I have something like this...

```
Table 1

Company  City         State
A        Los Angeles  CA
B        San Diego    CA
C        New York     NY
.
.
.

Table 2
Primary Company   Secondary1 Secondary2 Secondary3 Secondary4
A                 B          C          X          Y
B                 A          C          Z          W
C                 A          B          W          X
```

Do I need another table for this? Should I just concatenate these 20+ secondary company fields into one column somehow? Any direction you could give would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this:

```
Table 1

Company  City         State
A        Los Angeles  CA
B        San Diego    CA
C        New York     NY
.
.
.

Table 2
Primary Company   Secondary
A                 B          
A                 C          
A                 X
A                 Y
B                 A
B                 C
B                 Z
B                 W
```

...

In this case you will have a relationship between table1, column1 and table2 column 1 and 2.  This is acceptable (though technically better if you use numbers instead of letters).

Comment: Right, okay. Thanks! It is actually a little more complicated, because there's other information in Table 2 associated with each primary company's relationship with the others, but your suggestion got my started on the right track, I think.

Comment: Table 2 is a table of the relationships between companies, it is ok to have other information related to the relationship.  you want to avoid putting information in that table that will be duplicated elsewhere or is unrelated to the companies' relationships, and you may want to consider adding a primary key in the form of an id to identify each relationship

Comment: Right on. Thanks @Mark_Eng !